# Setting a cookie for cURL to use

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I am retrieving another page using cURL, and unless I have a certain cookie I cannot see the page content. The cookie name is `seepage` and its value must be set to 1 for me to see the page content.

I would like to load this page using cURL, and this is the script I have at the moment:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pixhost.org/images/531/1245992_untitled-2.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'tmpfile.tmp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'tmpfile.tmp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'tmpfile.tmp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);

?>
```

However, $result is an empty variable for which I can confirm with `if(empty($result))`. How would I set cURL to use a cookie called `seepage` with the cookie value being `1`?

Thanks.

Comment: You might wish to use a network debugger (Wireshark, Fiddler, etc) to confirm that your cookie really isn't being sent.

Answer (score 14):

The value of the cookie is 'seepage=1':

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'seepage=1');
```

and you'll need to remove the existing line for CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE

Comment: +1 - See the documentation on the php site (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), and the section on the CURLOPT_COOKIE option.