# PHP : How to call file using cookies with curl?

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I need to call a file using cookies. In this file if cookies are not created, we create them and we refresh the page thanks to header() function : everything is OK.

The thing I tried is :

```
$ch=curl_init($url_file);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output=curl_exec ($ch);
```

When I call that file with curl, cookies are empty. var_dump of my cookies display "NULL".

I don't want to get cookies with curl, just want to create them and use them when I'm calling the file.

Comment: You need to set the cookie with `CURLOPT_COOKIE` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995850/setting-a-cookie-for-curl-to-use

Comment: Cookies are created in the file I want to call with curl... :-/

Comment: Cookies have to be passed back-and-forth because of the stateless nature of HTTP. Edit your question with more details about your scenario so that we can understand.

Comment: When the cookie header comes back from the server, you need to store it somewhere so that you can pass it back. Take a look into `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` - https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-cookies/

Comment: I've done that, that was the only way ! It works great thanks you !